# MongoDB C# store local datetime

Tags: c#, mongodb

We have a system where we need to store local times from different time zones.
It is related to flight times where departures and arrival have to be stored in local time, but with a different timezone.

Converting to UTC doesn't help since when we retrieve the time for display, it needs to be in its original time zone and this information will have been lost by the conversion to UTC.

Should I then store the time zone offset and the UTC time and then rebuild the local time when we read the data?
or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You should store your datetime in a timestamp that follows the ISO 8601 ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

This way you store the time in UTC and the offset using a single timestamp.

Comment: so that's essentially storing it as the c# type DateTimeOffset, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's essential, without the offset you cannot get the time in the original offset back.